# Flash minting ether security considerations and attacks

Tags: security, attacks, defi, flash-loans

[Flash loans enable a class of attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89650/flash-loan-security-considerations-and-attacks) that have not been possible or observed as much in prior systems.

Flash minting ether is a concept that is starting to be implemented.
See [Example of flash minting ether](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89649/example-of-flash-minting-ether) (a question focused on the basics of flash minting).

Extending from the basics of flash minting, what additional security considerations and attacks does flash minting ether bring up, compared to flash loans?

Comment: I would rephrase `flash minting ether`, because it is misleading. This is flash minting of WETH, which is an ERC20 token used in some projects (e.g., uniswap). It is by no means a "temporary creation" of ether, as implied by the phrase  `flash minting ether`, but a "temporary creation" of WETH tokens. And as such, it is relevant only to specific systems which make use of WETH, and that is of a big difference from ETH, since the latter is an integral part of the blockchain, which is practically used everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

An example of Flash minting ether is WETH10...Their contract hasn't been audicted, but there are many logic in your background with prevent attack like burning and reverse all transaction if the same ammount of WETH10 don't return to the contract.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1E3Uuoj4DYEWGWpV2PzY1a8I86nCbgo52xL7xhNvNVj8/edit#slide=id.p

Comment: Is Austin Williams the author of the doc? It looks like solid reference. Thanks